# JSP Logout HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP file called "logout.jsp" that I am trying to use to logout of my web application:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Logout</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Logout successful!</h1>
        <%
            session.invalidate();
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using a link on each of my other pages which looks like:

```
<a href="/WEB-INF/logout.jsp">Log out</a>
```

However, whenever I click on the link I get an error saying:

```
Http Status 404 - Not Found
Type - Status Report
message - Not Found
description - The requested resource is not available
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've looked around and cannot seem to solve the issue

Cheers,

Comment: Do you have something like `/logout` or `logout.jsp` in your paths?

Comment: Sorry, could you please elaborate? I'm very new to MVC programming in Java. What paths do you mean?

Comment: When you click on that link, it should be defined at the server side so that it knows what page to load.

Comment: @Samuel So at the moment, the jsp file is just in a folder called "WEB-INF" in my netbeans project. I have edited my post above to show the file path however, it still gives the same error. Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I see you've updated the post, do you have any other links working? like `index.jsp`.

Comment: It seems that it's the actual link that does not work. Currently, pages are navigated with servlet controllers that make use of: "request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/myjsp.jsp").forward(request, response)" which works correctly

Comment: Solved, apparently the "WEB-INF" folder is not publicly accessible so I had to move the logout.jsp outside of that folder. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Great! You can answer your own question so that it might be helpful to someone else in the future.